# Truthy Expression Without an If Statement

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to evaluate a Javascript truthy as an expression that returns the true/false result?  Specifically it would be nice to not have to write an if statement to do this.  I have the following code which does what I'm talking about but still requires an if/else clause:

```
(myVariable)?true:false
```

This code seems redundant when all I want is the truthy value of myVariable.  Any code provided should be able to be run in a browser console and return the proper true/false value.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with `myVariable`?  If I am reading the question right, I think you just want `!!myVariable`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the reasons why you want a truthy value to be saved as true instead of leaving it as the value itself? I can’t picture a situation when this would be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are fooling yourself if you think some magic trick can convert a variable into a strict true/false boolean without an implicit `if`.

These 3 lines:

```
return (myVariable) ? true : false

return !!myVariable

if (myVariable) { return true } else {return false}
```

Internally all do exactly the same.

I can see plenty of use cases to convert a variable into a strict true or false boolean. But why do you want this without a (possibly implicit) `if`? Do you think there's some performance issue with that?

Answer (score 1):

When you apply a `!` to a JavaScript object it makes it into a "not" boolean, so when we apply two `!!` is simply makes a "not not" boolean.  Thus we can simply do `!!myVariable`

Logical NOT (!)     !expr   Returns false if its single operand that can be converted to true; otherwise, returns true. Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators

Note your ternary operator is on the ref linked page as well.

For example:

```
var myVariable = "fred"; // truthy variable

console.log(!!myVariable); // logs true
console.log(typeof !!myVariable); // logs boolean
```

For clarity:

```
var myVariable = true;
var myNew = !myVariable; // false
var myNewNew = !!myVariable; // true again
```

Answer (score 0):

`!!myVariable` will do the trick:

`!!{truthy value} -> !false -> true`